# Reading JSON object from URL doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript

Relatively new to JS, and I feel like I'm probably doing something wrong.

I have JQuery downloaded and linked to properly in my script, which you can see in my code below.

```js
console.log("javascript is working");

$(function getRipple() {
  $.getJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ripple/.json",
    function(data) {
      $("reply").html(JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <h1>Ripple Ticker</h1>

  <div id="reply"></div>
```

When I try to pull the JSON data from the URL in the script and then display it in a div, it doesn't return anything.

I've tried displaying it to the console but it also doesn't display anything, so I'm obviously doing something wrong within my JS. Apologies if this is a really simple error, but I can't really figure it out.

Comment: I hit that URL through the browser and it gives me a 404. I think the last part of the URL is incomplete

Comment: Your url should be https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ripple.json

Comment: You should check the Network tab of browser developer tools (F12) - it would have said 404 in there.

Comment: Just remove `.json` from the url and it works

Comment: @Axnyff The url you suggest is wrong

Comment: At least it returns a valid json object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL seems wrong, I tried with `https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ripple/` and it works fine, also you need to change the selector to `#reply`.

```js
console.log("javascript is working");

$(function getRipple() {
  $.getJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ripple/",
    function(data) {
      $("#reply").html(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <h1>Ripple Ticker</h1>

  <pre id="reply"></pre>
```

Comment: Yeah this works perfectly, cheers. I'm also trying to do something slightly different and pull a ripple price from a different website and display it below, but the code isn't working. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c9a786d5238faa9b029b2e19423fbd3b Any ideas with this?

Comment: @Ajek I commented on your GIST, please check it!

Answer (score -1):

Remove '.json' in your URL and it should work for you.

Comment: So I removed the '.json' and now it displays in the console. How do I get it so that it displays within the div?